# how to remove space in the middle using c#

Tags: c#, removing-whitespace

how to remove space in the middle using c#? I have the `string name="My Test String"` and I need the output of the string as `"MyTestString"` using c#.
Please help me.

Answer (score 45):

Write like below

```
name = name.Replace(" ","");
```

Comment: How about name = name.Replace(" ", string.Empty); ? Same meaning, but more conventional :)

Answer (score 9):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class TestProgram
{
    static string RemoveSpaces(string value)
    {
    return Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+", " ");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
    string value = "Sunil  Tanaji  Chavan";
    Console.WriteLine(RemoveSpaces(value));
    value = "Sunil  Tanaji\r\nChavan";
    Console.WriteLine(RemoveSpaces(value));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Fastest and general way to do this (line terminators, tabs will be processed as well). Regex powerful facilities don't really needed to solve this problem, but Regex can decrease performance.

```
new string
    (stringToRemoveWhiteSpaces
       .Where
       (
         c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)
       )
       .ToArray<char>()
    )
```

Comment: Avoid code only answers